# How to Handle complex payload in Node js FormData

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, multipartform-data, form-data

I have the following JSON format which i need to send and save to DB.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Tilte",
    "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
    "image": //IMAGE FILE
  },
  {
    "title": "Tilte",
    "images": [
      //IMAGE FILES
    ]
  },
    {
    "title": "Tilte",
    "image": //IMAGE FILE
  },
]
```

Here the array contains unknown length of data,some of it contains image file uploading and some of it have multiple image file uploading. i have seen this working with in a laravel server. but i dont know how to achieve this with Node JS. And also i have only seen a single way to pass array in formdata which is after Stringify the array. but in this case i cant do that because of the files. and what happens when the array has a large length, which String cant carry.

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach 1 :

Before sending it to the API Encode your image file accordingly from the client side. Once after encoding your payload would like something like this.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Tilte",
        "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAw"
    },
    {
        "title": "Tilte",
        "images": [
            "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgF", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgF"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Tilte",
        "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwME5I"
    }
]
```

Then it can be passed to you backend API.

#### Approach 2 :

If you dont know how to implement node js server refer the below steps :

1. Install `npm install express multer`
2. create app.js file add following lines below :

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Set up Multer for handling file uploads
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  // Handle the uploaded data here
  const { title, content, images } = req.body;
  const image = req.file;

  console.log('Received Data:');
  console.log('Title:', title);
  console.log('Content:', content);

  if (image) {
    console.log('Image:', image.filename);
  }

  if (images && Array.isArray(images)) {
    console.log('Images:', images);
  }

  res.send('Data uploaded successfully!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

3. Create an uploads folder in the same directory as your app.js file to store the uploaded images.
4. Run the node server using `node app.js`
5. Using the below CURL command upload images or image

   `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[ { "title": "Title", "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text...", "image": "@/path/to/your/image.jpg" }, { "title": "Title", "images": [ "@/path/to/your/image1.jpg", "@/path/to/your/image2.jpg" ] }, { "title": "Title", "image": "@/path/to/your/image3.jpg" } ]' http://localhost:3000/upload`

Note: Make sure to replace @/path/to/your/image.jpg with the actual paths to your image files.

Comment: Here you are passing image as base64 image and recieving with req.file. is this right?

Comment: If you are going ahead with 2nd approach you dont need to encode. But if you are going ahead with first better to encode it with base64

Comment: And another concern is conversion to base64 image will lower the quality

Comment: I dont think so. If thats the case go with approach 2

Comment: for the second approach, path to image is loal path. how can that be a file upload?

Comment: You can change it accordingly to accept a string (which is base 64)